# System.AccessViolationException break on thrown

Tags: c#

I am trying to resolve a AccessViolationException that is created when returning from native to managed code. Visual studio 2015 / .Net 4.0. I went into the Exception Settings and selected to Break when thrown for AccessViolationException. However that does not appear to occur. I read that there are new behaviors for this exception here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Would that prevent the debugger from breaking on the throw?

More details, and maybe you are right the VS simply cannot give me more. The native code returns a struct to the managed code. The struct is defined in managed so that the marshaling can occur. I can step through the native code and the method completes. The debugger ends up on the managed method which was pinvoked. I was hoping the debugger would stop at a point that would allow me to identify the offending memory component

Comment: Give us more info please. Do you mean unmanaged code or managed unsafe code? Note, that AccessViolationException is .Net managed object and it is created when the program already returned (it probably just wraps information from unmanaged exception). I'm not sure that in general case VS will be able to detect the point at which unmanaged code threw (do you at least have access to this unmanaged code)?

Comment: Show us your interop code.  We can't guess at what the problem is.